# Pull woocommerce checkout first name field value on checkout submit

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, api, woocommerce

**Desired outcome** Looking to to pull the first name field value on checkout submit

The referenced snippet below is in `form-checkout.php` template before the start of the checkout form.

For some reason the checkout submit button is not responding to `woocommerce_checkout_place_order` when I create a simple form with new field and a test button it works via something like `button1`...

```
 echo $cm_billing_first_name = $_POST['billing_first_name'];


 if(isset($_POST['woocommerce_checkout_place_order'])) { 
         var_export($order);

try {

$order = $pf->post('orders', [
    'recipient' => [
        'name' => $cm_billing_first_name,
        'address1' => '172 W Street Ave #105',
        'city' => 'Burbank',
        'state_code' => 'CA',
        'country_code' => 'US',
        'zip' => '91502',
    ],
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This worked**  - moved everything to a new php file then used the action `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` to call a function directly after the order is submitted then `include` the directory to the new file. Clean.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'send_order_to_printful', 1 );


function send_order_to_printful( ) {

include '/home/***/public_html/wp-content/themes/***-child/woocommerce/checkout/printful.php';
 }
```